# Making EXE Installer from Netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I'm trying to make my java application distributable.But when trying to package as exe installer from netbeans I'm getting this error. Can't understand how to do it. please help. thank you

`Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "iscc" (in directory "C:\Users\Hansi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\medical"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\Hansi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\medical\nbproject\build-native.xml:441: Error:
JavaFX native packager requires external Inno Setup 5+ tools installed and included on PATH to create EXE installer. See http://www.jrsoftware.org/`

Comment: "JavaFX native packager requires external Inno Setup 5+ tools installed and included on PATH to create EXE installer. See http://www.jrsoftware.org/" - have you done this?

Comment: sorry Ravn, your link doesn't open

Comment: The link was copied directly from your question. You need extra software installed!

Comment: I have installed innosetup and included on PATH.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you are invoking wants to run a program on your system which you don't have.

You need to install that program properly so it can be invoked manually from the command line, and try again. Instructions can be found in the stack trace. If the website is down you will need to find an alternate source.